# Add languageHints to Google Cloud Vision

Tags: python, google-vision

how can I add languageHints to my google cloud vision python code.
From https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages I know that it is supported but I do not know how to implement it into the code.

```
from google.cloud import vision
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision.types.Image(content=content)

response = client.text_detection(image=image)
texts = response.text_annotations
print('Texts:')

for text in texts:
    print('\n"{}"'.format(text.description))

    vertices = (['({},{})'.format(vertex.x, vertex.y)
                for vertex in text.bounding_poly.vertices])

    print('bounds: {}'.format(','.join(vertices)))
```

I think I have to do it like this:

```
context = imageContext.setLanguageHints("ko")
response = client.text_detection(image=image, context=context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's late, I hope this help's another people.

Based on [this](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/gapic/v1/types.html?highlight=hints#google.cloud.vision_v1.types.ImageContext.language_hints), you could do something like this:

```
image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
context = vision.types.ImageContext(language_hints=['ko'])
response = client.text_detection(image=image, image_context=context)
```

Note that the `language_hints` parameter expects a list.